# Is CUDA hardware needed at compile time?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu

Is installed CUDA capable graphics card necessary (in Linux) for compiling CUDA programs with `nvcc`? Or one can compile programs everywhere and run only on such systems?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a graphics card is not necessary for compilation.

You don't even need one to run the program; you can have it emulated in software.

**UPDATE** Ok, apparently, SW emulation hasn't been supported since CUDA 3.0.

Comment: I'm not sure emulation mode still exists in CUDA 4.0+, does it?

Comment: @James: I honestly don't know; it's been a while since I did anything with CUDA...

Comment: there is no more emulation mode since CUDA 3.0